# How to remove array index from file using vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, notepad++, sublimetext3

I have one situation there I need to remove the array index from file

```
[0] => https://demo.com/alabama/18-wheeler-towing
[1] => https://demo.com/alabama
[2] => https://demo.com/alabama/winston-county/18-wheeler-towing
[3] => https://demo.com/alabama/winston-county
[4] => https://demo.com/service/18-wheeler-towing-addison-al
[5] => https://demo.com/alabama/winston-county/addison
```

I have a file there there thousands of link but I need something like

```
https://demo.com/alabama/18-wheeler-towing
https://demo.com/alabama
https://demo.com/alabama/winston-county/18-wheeler-towing
https://demo.com/alabama/winston-county
https://demo.com/service/18-wheeler-towing-addison-al
https://demo.com/alabama/winston-county/addison
```

**How can I remove this array index using any file editor like vs code**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On Visual Studio Code you may use the [multi cursor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor), add as many cursors you want in either direction and delete the indexes by pressing the backspace or delete key.

> VS Code supports multiple cursors for fast simultaneous edits. You can add secondary cursors (rendered thinner) with Alt+Click. Each cursor operates independently based on the context it sits in. A common way to add more cursors is with Ctrl+Alt+Down or Ctrl+Alt+Up that insert cursors below or above

[image: GIF outlining how one may use the multicursor on VScode]

Comment: this multicursort i need to setup in vs code or it's already setup in vs code because i am not able to select like you shared screen short

Comment: You need to read the page I linked and follow the instructions. It's builtin. I'm on Windows and I pressed ctrl+alt+down 5 times with the caret initially behind the first "http"

Answer (score 0):

If the index of array may have more than 1 digit, you can do with Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?(?=https)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
.+?         # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
(?=https)   # positive lookahead, make sure we have "https" after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]